# Hide secondary rows in pivot chart but keep shown in pivot table Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a pivot table with a pivot chart that contains sets of two rows and a value field:

- **COUNTRY** -- a primary
- **COMPANY** -- a secondary
- **SALES** -- a value field

When I collapse all the secondary rows the chart looks exactly like I want it to because it only focuses on the COUNTRY totals. However when I expand, the chart becomes a mess. Is there a way to keep the chart focused only on the primary rows regardless if the secondary rows are expanded on the pivot table?

Here is a picture of the workbook collapsed:

[image]

Here is a picture where they are expanded:

[image]

You can understand my problem when you expand several hundred secondary rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do it.  Workaround can be to move the chart to a new sheet,  then create a new pivot table below it. So you can poem the groups without affecting the charts.  If you want to link filtering,  then use slicers (you can link them to both pivot tables).

Comment: Are you saying I can link the slicer of the chart with a new slicer of a new table? If so, I did not know that. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look on "Share a slicer by connecting to another PivotTable" at this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-PivotTable-data-249F966B-A9D5-4B0F-B31A-12651785D29D?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm6)